# Matlab axis labels missing in all figures

Tags: matlab

For some reason, none of my figures properly display the axis labels set in the usual way with xlabel('foo') etc. Just a small dotted outline of a box appears. Any ideas what this could be or how I could fix it?

Example screeny: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcIh0.jpg

Comment: Are you saving the figure to a file, or just showing it within matlab?  If you are saving it to a file, what filetype?

Comment: Just displaying it on the screen at the moment. I tried saving to a JPEG which has the same problem, including rendering the same, small, dotted boxes.

Comment: I also tried plotting a string with text(x,y,'foo'), which just adds another little empty box at the (x,y) coords.

Comment: The figure-creating code would help. Does it happen both in a 2D plot?

Comment: Yes, it happens in all figure windows, not created in any special way. The surf plot I posted was just computing a matrix of heights and then surf(mat). I also reinstalled matlab in a different directory and the new installation has the same problem. I believe it must be the configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen if you don't have the proper fonts installed. Take a look at [Missing fonts in Matlab in Fedora 10](http://linux.dsplabs.com.au/forums/fedora-linux-help/missing-fonts-in-matlab-in-fedora-10-t126.html). The installation of the right fonts will depend on your OS.

Comment: This was exactly the problem. Specifically, matlab was looking for Helvetica which wasn't installed. Thank you very much.